# Are there any alternatives to outputting mySQL data into XML via PHP? (for Google Maps API V3)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-maps-api-3, xml-parsing

So the Google Map API tutorial [Creating a Store Locator with PHP, MySQL & Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql) takes the output from the mySQL database and processes it into XML using php (excuse my amateur terminology).

My simple question is, is it absolutely necessary to output mySQL data into XML?

Is there no other way whereby the data can be grabbed from mySQL and converted into variables for use in js functions elsewhere? with the example, anybody is able to run a simple query and see all my data? It doesnt seem very secure and in which case why not just simply echo the mySQL query results?

Comment: You can always write your own dynamical function that creates an xml file..

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it. The root problem of the data being available for download is not really solvable.  The only possible solutions are 1. pay for a private table and use FusionTablesLayer, 2. create tiles with the geographic data on your server and overlay them on the map.  In either of those two cases the data is only available visually and when someone clicks on something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it is not strictly required to convert the data into XML, this standard format is well suited to represent structured data. But you may very well decide to use JSON for example, or any home-brewed format of your liking. Do not reinvent the wheel though.

The second issue you are rising is not related to the output format, but rather is a problem of access control.

As far as I can tell from a very quick glance at the tutorial, indeed anyone could connect to your server and extract data.

In order to limit access to the data (i.e. limit access to the script `phpsqlsearch_genxml.php`), you could, for example, verify the presence of a session cookie in the ajax request. Implement such a check at the very beginning of the script, and perhaps generate an error if the user is not logged.

Comment: So let me see if i understand this correctly...
1) there is no way of processing server site data without physically displaying this somewhere ie. in a php script, even using AJAX?

2) how would a session cookie limit the access to the processing script? I'm suprised there is no real solution to protecting db content that you require on the front end.

Comment: 1) The thing is, you want the browser to send a query to the server, and you want the server to respond. This is the very definition of a client-server application, and there is no work around. The only thing you can do is protect the access to the server by authenticating the client. This is what most web sites do: they ask you for a password. 2) There are several real, standard, authentication solutions over HTTP, one of them is session cookies. You need to realise that from the server point of view there is no difference between an Ajax call and a good ol'click on a `<a href>` link.

Comment: If I request authentication from the client on every attempt to retrieve the markers via the processing PHP script, this interrupts the marker creation on the map. This is clearly impractical, or have i misunderstood the suggestion?

Comment: Once the user is logged in, there is no need for her to type the password again. Remember that an Ajax call is, from the server point of view, nothing but a regular HTTP request. The session cookie, as well as any cookie, is sent along with the Ajax request. In the script that handles the Ajax request, check authentication exactly in the same way as in any other script in your application.